# Problema con height en div de Twitter inmerso en página web

Tags: html, twitter-api

Buen día a todos

Estoy usando el siguiente código para embeber Twitter dentro de una página web, me gustaría que el height se controlara a un tamaño especifico pero se carga demasiado largo.

El código que uso es el siguiente:

```
<div class="col-md-4" height="300px">
                        <div class="info" >                             
                            <h4 class="info-title">Twitter</h4>
                            <div >
                                <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/LuisAlfonsoEsc">Tweets de Luis Alfonso</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
                            </div>                              
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

La página la pueden ve en:http://health.smart-coast.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la [configuración](https://publish.twitter.com/) del widget de twitter hay una opción llamada **set customization options** en donde se puede especificar la altura y otros parámetros.

Si lo quieres modificar manualmente, el parámetro se llama `data-height`:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="info" >                             
        <h4 class="info-title">Twitter</h4>
        <div>
            <a class="twitter-timeline" data-height="600" href="https://twitter.com/LuisAlfonsoEsc">Tweets de Luis Alfonso</a>
            <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        </div>                              
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfecto! Muchas gracia por tu respuesta. Tienes conocimiento para exactamente lo mismo con facebook e instagram? Estas dos redes irían justo a la derecha de donde ya esta ubicado Twitter.

Comment: para [facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/) solo añades los datos solicitados es igual para instagram tambien. Aquí hay una [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46792290) en inglés que te puede servir

Comment: aunque instagram en menos flexible, tiene menos opciones en comparación

Answer (score 1):

Una opción es usar la página https://publish.twitter.com/ y allí seleccionas "Embedded Timeline".

Luego selecciona el enlace "Set customization options" y allí establece las medidas y otros valores de configuración del Widget.

El siguiente código es el resultado de haber generado el Widget con la cuenta correspondiente y con un `height` de 300px.

```html
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-height="500" href="https://twitter.com/LuisAlfonsoEsc?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by LuisAlfonsoEsc</a>
<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```